# ERROR: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule' angular

Tags: angular, devextreme, devextreme-angular

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: @Sajeetharan which component code? i use devextreme in angular project so tell me please

Comment: your app.module.ts

Comment: @Sajeetharan 
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

Comment: post your code in the question and format it without adding a picture

Comment: Now? @Sajeetharan

Comment: do you export  class AppModule { } ?

Comment: export class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
@fatemefazli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your app.module.ts should be:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and in your main.ts add :

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';



if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
@fatmee this also show error on AppModule

Comment: @fatmee now this error 
ERROR in Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options

Comment: are you sure your main.ts is in src folder?

Comment: @fatmee yes 100%

Comment: ok lets try again, you change the app.module.ts to what i mentioned and change back the main.ts to what was before, now whats the result?

Comment: @fatmee chek this i m importing this code in angular project 
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/WebAPIService/Angular/Light/